# Run SolrCloud on different machine

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to configure SolrCloud on more than one Server/machine so that it one server is fail another replica can serve that request.

I can successfully run SolrCloud on single machine with two node on different port address. I am refering this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Getting+Started+with+SolrCloud)

But How can I run it on different machine. What configuration I need to do to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You provide Solr with the address to the Zookeeper ensemble you'll be using to distribute the workload. It's highly recommended to run Zookeeper by itself instead of using the one bundled with Solr. In the last example in the link you've provided, you can see the `-z` parameter that provides the connection list of zookeeper instances available. Solr uses Zookeeper to keep its cluster state and available servers synced across instances.